# Two NodeJS apps in a single gear on Openshift or a single Heroku dyno

Tags: node.js, heroku, openshift

Looking for a way to run two NodeJS apps on a single gear on Openshift Online (Premium) or the equivalent with Heroku and a dyno. Each app will live in it's own folder in the file system and have its own server.js file, listening on a different port.

Each app will have its own domain.

Each app can have its own git repo, or both apps can be in the same repo (different folder) if separate repos are not possible.

An alternate (and simple) solution would be to run each app on its own gear/dyno, but these apps are low traffic and do not justify the cost of running them separately.

Note: on Openshift, the apps run the following cartridges: nodejs-0.10 mongodb-2.4

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so that would be possible because the PORT to run node app is fixed by these PaaS platforms, so, you cant run two apps on same port.

A workaround can be using vHost and cluster(I haven't tried it myself)
Write a third repo with server.js and this third repo would be bound as main repo on Heroku/Openshift

Write some shell script that runs on Post install/download of the third repo, and it downloads the other two repositories on your remote machine

And, then in the third repo use the code below

```
// server.js
var cluster = require('cluster');
var express = require('express');
var app = express ();

if(cluster.isMaster) {
        cluster.fork ();
}
else {
    app
        .use( express.vhost('www.site1.com'), require(PATH_TO_FIRST_REPO_SERVER.JS).app ) )
        .use( express.vhost('www.site2.com'), require(PATH_TO_SECOND_REPO_SERVER.JS).app ) )
        .listen(8080);
}
```